# Blazor EditForm and Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, blazor, fluentvalidation

Just putting together a wrapper based on EditForm and using Fluent Validation. I've created two properties on this form as below:

```
if (ModelValidation)
{
    editContext.OnValidationRequested +=
        (sender, eventArgs) => ValidateModel((EditContext)sender, messages);
}

if (FieldValidation)
{
    editContext.OnFieldChanged +=
        (sender, eventArgs) => ValidateField(editContext, messages, eventArgs.FieldIdentifier);
}
```

This allows validation to be either on OnFieldChanged (value changes, validated on exit field) or when a submit button is pressed (OnValidationRequested)

However, if I have say a text field which is empty (which should be non-empty) tab out of it the OnFieldChanged() handler does not fire...(not surprising the field hasn't changed). Is there a way of forcing the call to OnFieldChanged() or a kill focus handler without resorting to javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought this was interesting so I took a look at the source code of Blazor's `InputText` class on the ASP .NET Core project of GitHub here:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputText.cs

You'll notice that there is only one event handler and it's for the `onchange` event raised by the browser when the user changes the value in the text box.

```
builder.AddAttribute(4, "onchange", EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString));
```

The event you want to subscribe to is `onblur`, which is raised when the user clicks or tabs out of a field regardless of whether they changed it or not, and it's not been done.

I couldn't find it anywhere in InputText or InputBase (from which InputText derives) but it's there somewhere because this seems to work:

```
@page "/"
<InputText @onblur="DoSomething" />

@code
{
    private void DoSomething()
    { // Your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: excellent I will check that out, thanks for your help benjamin

Comment: Glad to have helped. If it works, please mark it as the answer. If not, let me know and I'll have another think for you!

Comment: I have taken another look at this and changed by answer above.